# Google Drive - Retrieve contents of publicly shared file programatically

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

Is it possible to retrieve contents of a publicly shared file programatically. I tried their demo. It does have code to retrieve data am able to retrieve data from my account with which I login with their demo. If I try to access a file from another account which is public am not able to retrieve it.